# better way to select random mailbox database

Tags: powershell

Can someone tell me a better way to select random mailbox database?

We have our mailbox databases such as Archive-Database-01 ,  Archive-Database-02.

Here is my script :

```
$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).Date

$Users = Get-ADUser -Filter {(emailaddress -like "*@contoso.com" -and Enabled -eq $true -and sAMAccountName -like "tst*")} -SearchBase "OU=USERS,DC=contoso,DC=local" -SearchScope Subtree -Properties * | Where-Object { $_.whenCreated -ge $date } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty samaccountname


foreach ($User in $Users){

        Enable-Mailbox -Identity "$user" -Archive -ArchiveDatabase "Archive-Database-01"
        Set-Mailbox -Identity "$user" -RetentionPolicy "Archive Policy"
 }
```

Comment: Any database, or only one of databases starting with `Archive`?

Comment: If you have an array of database names, then you can use `$db = $yourArrayOfDatabaseNames | Get-Random` Then use $db for parameter -ArchiveDatabase

Comment: @Theo  thanks so I want to  pick a random 50% of mailbox database names. I mean it will pick db01 then db02 then db01 then db02 and so on

Answer (score 0):

As commented, if you have a list of archive database names, you can use `Get-Random` to pick one of these names.

Also, I would redefine your filter to be a **string** rather than a scriptblock:

```
# the list of archive database names as string array
$dbNames = 'Archive-Database-01', 'Archive-Database-02', 'Archive-Database-X'
$date    = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).Date
# just to shorten the Get-ADUser line, define $filter as variable
$filter  = "EmailAddress -like '*@contoso.com' -and Enabled -eq $true -and SamAccountName -like 'tst*'"
$Users   = Get-ADUser -Filter $filter -SearchBase "OU=USERS,DC=contoso,DC=local" -SearchScope Subtree -Properties Created, EmailAddress | 
           Where-Object { $_.Created -ge $date } 

foreach ($user in $Users){
    $db = $dbNames | Get-Random
    $user | Enable-Mailbox -Archive -ArchiveDatabase $db
    $user | Set-Mailbox -RetentionPolicy "Archive Policy"
}
```

---

As per your comments, perhaps you mean to do something like below:

```
# suppose you have 4 databases
$dbNames = 'Archive-Database-01', 'Archive-Database-02', 'Archive-Database-03','Archive-Database-04'
# get a random array index to start off with
$index = 0..($dbNames.Count - 1) | Get-Random

# then rotate through the indices to get the next index in order
foreach ($user in $Users){
    $user | Enable-Mailbox -Archive -ArchiveDatabase $dbNames[$index]
    $user | Set-Mailbox -RetentionPolicy "Archive Policy"
    $index = ($index + 1) % $dbNames.Count
}
```

Comment: Something like `$dbNames = $dbNames | Get-Random -Count ($dbNames.Count / 2)` you mean?

Comment: @Arbelac Ok, so that would mean you pick two items from the list and use Get-Random on that I guess? How many databases do you have?

Comment: @Arbelac Please see my edit. You can use a rotating array index, starting off with a random index and from that rotate through the next one in order.

Comment: @Arbelac Yes, please see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75545321/9898643) on that one