# try catch block inside nested foreach loop

Tags: powershell

I will upload file under folder onTeams with PowerShell. I am using some try/catch block inside if/else statement.  How can we improve my script? Or what do you recommend? I want to know is whether there is any way to make this code run better. I'm new to Powershell, so I don't know what looks like bad code or good code.

Let's say, I've run my script in November 2022. It will create a folder called `2022-10` under `"/sites/Team/Shared Documents/General/Documents/2022"`

Or I've run my script in February 2023. Firstly, it will create called 2023 mail folder for new year under `"/sites/Team/Shared Documents/General/Documents/` Then it will create folder called `2023-01` under `"/sites/Team/Shared Documents/General/Documents/2023"`

And so on.

My script:

```
#Config Variables
$SiteURL = "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/Team"
$SourceFilePath ="C:\Documents\report.csv"
$DestinationFolderPath = "/sites/Team/Shared Documents/General/Documents" #Server Relative URL
 
Try {
    #Connect to PnP Online
    
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -ClientId "47bf0ca0-1d8a-xxxx-xxx-xxxx" -Tenant 'tenant.onmicrosoft.com' -Thumbprint <Thumbprint>

}
catch {
    write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor Red
}



$year= get-date -Format yyyy

$FolderURL = $DestinationFolderPath + "/" + $year

#Try to Get the Folder
$Folder = Get-PnPFolder -Url $FolderURL -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
 
#sharepoint online powershell To check if folder exists
If($Folder -ne $null)
{
    Write-Host -f Green "Folder exists!"
    Try{
        
        
        $d = (get-date).AddMonths(-1).ToString("yyyy-M")
        
        $FolderPATHLastMonth = $DestinationFolderPath + "/" + $year
        
        Add-PnPFolder -Name $d -Folder $FolderPATHLastMonth
        
        $DestinationFolderPath = $FolderPATHLastMonth + "/" + $d
        
        Add-PnPFile -Path $SourceFilePath -Folder $DestinationFolderPath -ErrorAction Stop
        
       }
    catch{
        echo $_.Exception
    }
    
    
}
Else
{
    Write-Host -f Yellow "Folder does not exists!"
    Try{
        
        
        
        Add-PnPFolder -Name $year -Folder $DestinationFolderPath
        
        $d2 = (get-date).AddMonths(-1).ToString("yyyy-M")
        
        $FolderPATHLastMonth = $DestinationFolderPath + "/" + $year
        
        Add-PnPFolder -Name $d2 -Folder $FolderPATHLastMonth
        
        $DestinationFolderPath = $FolderPATHLastMonth + "/" + $d2
        
        Add-PnPFile -Path $SourceFilePath -Folder $DestinationFolderPath -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch{
        echo $_.Exception
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: add exit 1 in catch block, If($Folder -ne $null) eq If($Folder)

Answer (score 0):

I think your code could be more concise by joining the two blocks of code together.
Also, since you are creating folders for the previous month, this could also mean the previous year, so if you run this in January 2023, It should create a folder called `2022-12`..

Please try:

```
# Config Variables
$SiteURL         = "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/Team"
$SourceFilePath  = "C:\Documents\report.csv"
$DestinationPath = "/sites/Team/Shared Documents/General/Documents" #Server Relative URL
$dateLastMonth   = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1)
$targetPath      = '{0}/{1:yyyy}' -f $DestinationPath, $dateLastMonth

try {
    # Connect to PnP Online
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -ClientId "47bf0ca0-1d8a-xxxx-xxx-xxxx" -Tenant 'tenant.onmicrosoft.com' -Thumbprint <Thumbprint>
}
catch {
    throw    # displays the exception and exits the script
}

# Try to Get the target folder and create it if it does not exist
$Folder = Get-PnPFolder -Url $targetPath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if (!$Folder) {
    Write-Host "Creating folder '$($dateLastMonth.Year)'" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    try {
        Add-PnPFolder -Name $dateLastMonth.Year -Folder $DestinationPath -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch { 
        throw    # displays the exception and exits the script
    }
}

try {
    $finalFolder = '{0:yyyy-M}' -f $dateLastMonth
    # create a variable for the final destination folder
    $DestinationPath = '{0}/{1}' -f $targetPath, $finalFolder

    # test if the final destination flder already exists and create it if not
    if (!(Get-PnPFolder -Url $DestinationPath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
        Write-Host "Creating folder '$finalFolder'" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        Add-PnPFolder -Name $finalFolder -Folder $targetPath -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    # add the local file to the new destination folder
    Add-PnPFile -Path $SourceFilePath -Folder $DestinationPath -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch{
    Write-Warning "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
}
```

<sup>It may be better for sorting purposes if you do not create final destination folders in date format `'yyyy-M'`, but rather `'yyyy-MM'`</sup>